# How to remove frame from a chart -pyplot -matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I know this sound way simple but still google couldn't help me with the way it needed to be done

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure()

languages =['Python', 'SQL', 'Java', 'C++', 'JavaScript']
pos = np.arange(len(languages))
popularity = [56, 39, 34, 34, 29]

plt.bar(pos, popularity, align='center')
plt.xticks(pos, languages)
plt.ylabel('% Popularity')
plt.title('Top 5 Languages for Math & Data \nby % popularity on Stack Overflow', alpha=0.8)

# remove all the ticks (both axes), and tick labels on the Y axis
plt.tick_params(top='off', bottom='off', left='off', right='off', labelleft='off', labelbottom='on')

plt.show()
```

Comment: `plt.axis('off')` removes ticks and spines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to remove the ugly frames from matplotlib.pyplot
charts:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.box(False)
```

or

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for spine in plt.gca().spines.values():
spine.set_visible(False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add to your script, this will remove the axes from the chart:

```
plt.axis('off')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using `.axis()` method.

Here is the code statement you need to add:

```
plt.axis('off')
```

You will get this output:

[image]